# how to store the mapping table of IPv6 to residential address

Tags: google-maps, ipv6, ipv4

We know IPv6 has 128 bits which will have 2^128 IP addresses. 
If we store all the IPv6 addresses, we need 2^128 * 2^4 Byte / 2 ^ 30 = 2 ^ 102 GB which is a forbidden number.

Now my question is if we need maintain a mapping table from IPv6 address to a physical address, how do we do that?

Let us think how Google map locates us. Google map should store a giant table mapping from ip address to residential addresses. So when you visit Google map, Google map will query the table to find your residential address. My question is how does Google store IPv6 since it will a huge space if all of IPv6 are stored in the table

Comment: You don't store every address. You only store the addresses you actually use.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am not storing the table. I am asking how Google stores the IPv6 mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

```
ip neighbour              (linux)
ip ntable                 (linux)
```

see also here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228469/whats-ndisc-cache

Comment: It is not actually what I am asking for. Let us think how Google map locates us. Google map should store  a giant table mapping from ip address to residential addresses. So when you visit Google map, Google map will query the table to find your residential address. My question is how does Google store IPv6 since it will a huge space if all of IPv6 are stored in the table.

Comment: Sorry, I read only the first part of the question and misunderstood "physical address". The mapping of ip-addresses to location on the Earth is done in  similar way as with IPv4 - with ip/geo data bases, normally you don't store single IPv6 addresses, you assign some prefixes to that location. A lot of mobile devices report the location to Google, so it is no big problem to recognize which ip/network is more mobile and which ip/network is more or less statically placed at a specific location.

Comment: And of course. Everyone can use the RIR-data. That's not very precise, but a first point to start from and to check if the measurements are plausible otherwise a VPN may involved.